# Why am I getting AttributeError: module 'geoip2' has no attribute 'databse'

Tags: python-3.x, networking, geolocation, maxmind, geoip2

This is the code that I was executing and this is even the example that was given in the documentation of the geoip2 made by maxmind can anyone tell me what was the problem

import geoip2.database

with geoip2.databse.Reader('/path/to/GeoLite-ASN.mmdb') as reader:

```
response = reader.asn('203.0.113.0')

response.autonomous_system_organization
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am unable to find the location of the specified ip address using geoip2  it showing an Attribute Error  module geoip2 has no attribute databse